# Meu site fica bagunçado no Microsoft Edge, Firefox e no Safari. Como Resolver esse problema?

Tags: html, css

Meu site pega no Chrome e Opera, mas quando testo nesses outros navegadores fica bagunçado, mais, no Edge.

**Edge-**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Safari-**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Firefox é o que tem menos erros-**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu Código:**

```css
/*--------------------Confgurações primarias css--------------------*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700); 

*{margin:0; padding:0; border:0; list-style:none; vertical-align:baseline;}
img{max-width:100%;}
*, *:before, *:after{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
a{text-decoration:none; list-style:none;}

.clearfix:after, .clearfix:before{content:""; display:table;}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;}
/*--------------------Confgurações do topo--------------------*/

header{background-color:#222; width:100%; height:70px;} 
.topo{width:1110px; height:auto; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
.logo{width:184px; margin:0 auto; float:left; margin-top:10px;}

/*--------------------Confgurações da caixa de busca--------------------*/

.container-buscar{width:1110px; margin:0 auto;}
.search-box{min-width:130px;float:right; margin-top:-41px;}/*71px;*/
.search-area{width:150px; height:36px; outline:none; border:none; position:relative; z-index:9999; background:#FFF; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:1em; margin-right:-1px;}
.search-button{width:35px; height:36px; position:relative; z-index:9999; left:-4px; top:2px; outline:none; border:none; background:#FF7F00; cursor:pointer; z-index:9999;;}
button:hover{background:#000;}

/*--------------------Confgurações do menu--------------------*/

nav{width:100%; height:42px; background-color:#4682B4; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#fff;}
.nav-menu{max-width:1110px; margin:0 auto; width:100%; text-align:left;}
nav ul {list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative; min-width:200px;z-index:99;}
nav ul li{display:inline-block;}
nav ul li:hover{background-color:#000;}
nav ul li a, visited{color:#FFF; display:block; padding:10px; text-decoration:none;}
nav ul li:hover ul{display:block;}
nav ul ul{display:none; position:absolute; background-color:#222;}
nav ul ul li{display:block;}
nav ul ul li a:hover{color:#fff;}
.menu-fixo{top:0; position:fixed !important; z-index:999;}

/*--------------------Confgurações Destaques--------------------*/

.main{width:1150px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto; height:500px; overflow:hidden;}
.slideshow{width:100%; display:block; height:auto;}
.sld-left{width:65%; height:auto; float:left;}
.sld-right-top{width:35%; height:auto; float:right;}
.sld-right-bottom{width:35%; height:auto; float:right; margin-top:-4px;}
.slideshow a, visited{text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;}
.sld-left h2{float:left; font-size:40px; line-height:43px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; position:relative; top:-150px; left:10px; right:-10px;}
.sld-right-top h2{float:left; font-size:25px; line-height:27px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; position:relative; z-index:99; margin-top:-90px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:-5px;}
.sld-right-bottom h2{float:right; font-size:25px; line-height:27px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; position:relative; top:-90px; left:5px; right:-5px; z-index:1;}
.slideshow h2:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

/*--------------------Configurações dos artigos--------------------*/

.container-conteudo-db-at{width:1110px; margin:0 auto; height:auto;}

.corpo-artigos{width:100%; height:auto; margin:80px 0 0 0; clear:both; float:left;}
.title{margin:0 auto;}
.title p{font-size:25px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; position:relative; top:-30px;}
.line{border-top: 1px solid #ccc; width:550px;}
.artigos{height:auto; margin:0 auto 90px;}
.artigos a{color:#000;}
.loop{width:600px;}
.artigos h1{font-size:20px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; margin-left:200px; margin-top:-120px;} 
.artigos h1:hover{color:#4682B4; text-decoration:underline;}
.categoria p{font-size:14px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#FFF; margin-left:5px; margin-right:-5px;}
.categoria{position:absolute; background:rgba(255,127,0,0.8); width:56px; height:21px; margin-top:101px; margin-left:-56px;}

/*--------------------Configurações da sidebar--------------------*/

aside{background:#ccc; width:332px; height:auto; float:right; margin:-1535px 0 0 0; }
.text-1-sdb{background:#4682B4; float:left; width:332px; height:33px;}
.text-1-sdb p{font-size:20px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; margin-left:115px; margin-top:1px;}
.social-ctn img{margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px;}
.social-ctn{margin-left:60px;}
.social li{display:inline-block;}
.text-2-sdb{background:#4682B4; float:left; width:332px; height:33px; margin-top:5px;}
.text-2-sdb p{font-size:20px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; margin-left:100px; margin-top:1px;}
.container-mais-lidas{height:auto;}
.mais-lidas{margin-left:5px;}
.mais-lidas img{width:100px; height:70px; margin-top:4px; position:relative;}
.txt-ctn{float:right; width:250px; margin-right:-28px; margin-top:3px}
.mais-lidas h2{font-size:16px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
.mais-lidas a{color:#000;}
.mais-lidas h2:hover{color:#4682B4; text-decoration:underline;}
.categoria-sdb p{font-size:14px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#FFF; margin-left:5px; margin-right:-5px;}
.categoria-sdb{position:absolute; background:rgba(255,127,0,0.8); width:56px; height:21px; margin-top:53px; margin-left:-56px;}

/*--------------------Configurações do rodapé--------------------*/
.ir-ao-topo{float:right; cursor:pointer;}

/*--------------------Configurações ver-mais--------------------*/
.container-vmais{width:1110px; margin:0 auto;}
.ver-mais{font-size:22px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight:700; float:left; color:#000; margin-top:35px;}
.ver-mais:hover{color:#4682B4; text-decoration:underline;}
/*--------------------Configurações do rodapé--------------------*/

footer{background:#222; width:100%; height:72px; float:left;}
.copy-do-site p{width:460px; margin:0 auto; font-size:13px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#FFF; margin-top:45px;}
.copy-do-site a{color:#FFF;}
.copy-do-site a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.nav-rdp{width:500px; margin:0 auto;}
.nav-rdp ul li{display:inline-block; float:left; font-size:16px; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; padding:7px 0 0 25px;}
.nav-rdp a{color:#FFF;}
.nav-rdp :hover{text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="PT-BR">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content= "Se informe com notícias sobre tecnologia, games, internet, diversão, segurança, informática, programação." name="description">
<title>Dominção Tech</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="icon" href=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
<body>

<header>
 <div class="topo">
   <span class="logo clearfix"><a href="index.php" title="dominacaotech.com"><img src="img/logotipo.png" alt="Dominação Tech"/></a></span>
 </div>
</header>
 
 <nav>
  <ul class="nav-menu clearfix">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Games</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Notícias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Playstation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Xbox</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nintendo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Notícias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">IOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Windows phone</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dicas e ajudas</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
     <li><a href="#">Informática</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Notícias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Windows</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Linux</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Computadores</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Componentes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dicas e ajudas</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Internet</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Notícias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Segurança</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Redes Sociais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Diversão</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">TI</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Programação</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Novas tecnologias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dicas e tutoriais</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mercado financeiro</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
  
 <div class="container-buscar"> 
  <form action="search.html" class="search-box clearfix" method="get">
   <input class="search-area" name="q" placeholder="Buscar..." required/>
   <button class="search-button" type="submit" value="Buscar"><img src="img/tb-lupa.png" alt="Buscar no site"/></button>
 </form>
 </div>
 
 </nav>



<div class="main clearfix">
 <section class="slideshow">
 
    <div class="sld-left">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"><img src="img/img-01.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-top">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"><img src="img/img-02.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-bottom">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"><img src="img/img-03.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-left-2">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"><img src="img/img-01.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-top-2">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"><img src="img/img-02.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-bottom-2">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"><img src="img/img-03.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria"></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
 </section>
</div>  
 
  
<div class="container-conteudo-db-at"> 

 <section class="corpo-artigos clearfix">
 
 <div class="title">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <p>Últimas Notícias</p>
 </div>
     
  <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
 </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
 </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>  
 </article>
  
  <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
 
 <article class="artigos">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"/></a>
   <span class="categoria"><p>Games</p></span>
   <div class="loop">
   <a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h1>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h1></a>
   </div>
  </article>
  
 </section>


 <aside class="clearfix">
 
  <span class="text-1-sdb"><p>Siga-nos</p></span>
   <section class="social-ctn">
    <ul class="social">
     <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"/></a></li>
     <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"/></a></li>
     <li><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/collections/featured"><img src="img/Google+.png" alt="Google+" title="Google+"/></a></li>
     <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="img/Youtube.png" alt="Youtube" title="Youtube"/></a></li>
    </ul>
   </section>  
    
  <span class="text-2-sdb"><p>As mais lidas</p></span>
  
   <section class="container-mais-lidas">
     <article class="mais-lidas">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
     
     <div class="txt-ctn"><a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h2>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h2></a></div>
     <span class="categoria-sdb"><p>Games</p></span>
     </article> 
     
     <article class="mais-lidas">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
     
     <div class="txt-ctn"><a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h2>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h2></a></div>
     <span class="categoria-sdb"><p>Games</p></span>
     </article> 
     
     <article class="mais-lidas">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
     
     <div class="txt-ctn"><a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h2>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h2></a></div>
     <span class="categoria-sdb"><p>Games</p></span>
     </article> 
     
     <article class="mais-lidas">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
     
     <div class="txt-ctn"><a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h2>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h2></a></div>
     <span class="categoria-sdb"><p>Games</p></span>
     </article> 
     
     <article class="mais-lidas">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/ps4.png" alt="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"></a>
     
     <div class="txt-ctn"><a href="#" title="Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4"><h2>Um usuário conseguiu desbloquear oficialmente o PS4</h2></a></div>
     <span class="categoria-sdb"><p>Games</p></span>
     </article> 
    </section> 
    
 </aside>
</div>

 <span class="ir-ao-topo clearfix">
  <img src="img/back_to_top.png"/>
 </span> 
 
 <div class="container-vmais">
 <a class="ver-mais clearfix" href="#">Ver Mais conteúdo</a>
 </div>
 
 <footer>
  <section class="nav-rdp">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Anuncie</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sobre nós</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Política de privacidade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <span class="copy-do-site"><p>&copy; Copyright 2016 - Todos os direitos reservados ao <a href="index.php">dominacaotech.com.br</a></p></span>
 </footer>
  
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo! Conheceu o mal que assombra todo desenvolvedor front end **:)** Tem muito código para analisar, mas provavelmente um dos motivos são essas declarações com valores em *pixels*. Se você quer criar um layout fluído, vá de [porcentagem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWJZRbhKosM).

Comment: Vou criar responsivo, e que eu fiz primeiro para desktop.

Comment: Olá, esse problema deve ser devido aos valores em pixels, conforme foi falado na resposta acima. Mas mesmo que você não use porcentagem, pode estar resolvendo isso utilizando algum framework, como o Bootstrap que já tem todo um esquema de grid que reduz quase a 0 esses problemas de quebra de layout em outros navegadores. Link para o Bootstrap: [getbootstrap.com]

Comment: Então tenho que passar para medidas relativas. @JoãoVictor

Comment: Amigo, tente usar isso: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Amigo já usei o ccs normalize, mas não adiantou.

Comment: Já tentou usar Bootstrap ou grid 960?

Comment: Não pq nãos sei usar ele.

Comment: @GilmarSantos ao invés de usar o protocolo file, use um servidor local como o Apache e teste novamente, navegadores interpretam diferente a localização de resources css.

Comment: Uma dica que posso te dar, usar bootstrap nunca fará você aprender por que acontece isso. Se quiser aprender resolva seus problemas sem framework, se for algo pra produção que não tem tempo de aprender, aí sim é um motivo válido pra usar bootstrap.  Você tem algum link com essa página online? Analisando o HTML completo é bem mais fácil de encontrar o defeito.

Answer (score 2):

Pela experiência que tenho, um CÓDIGO BEM ESCRITO tem o mesmo efeito em qualquer navegador, podendo apenas ter alguma pequena variação na renderização da fonte ou outros detalhes mas que não alteram o layout desejado.

Analisando o seu código, ele me pareceu muito pesado e poluído, não respeitando as possíveis variações de interpretação do CSS e das tags que podem ocorrer entre um navegador e outro.

Sugiro que refaça todo o código, de forma concisa e limpa, construindo uma área após a outra (topo, corpo, coluna lateral, rodapé...) e ir testando nos navegadores um por um, e caso haja alguma diferença, procurar saber o que está errado até que fique igual em todos, e em seguida, passar para a próxima área e assim por diante.

Trabalho com front-end há mais de 10 anos e raramente testo meus códigos em outros navegadores (uso o Chrome) pois já sei o que um suporta e o outro não, e assim consigo fazer um código conciso em que o layout fique EXATAMENTE igual em todos.

Não estou julgando seu nível de conhecimento se você um profissional da área ou apenas está se aventurando, mas pelo o que estou vendo, precisa se aprimorar muito ainda. Boa sorte!

Comment: Hoje em dia está mais fácil fazer isso, duvido que ficava igual na época do Internet 6 ou 7 hehe, mas enfim, seria legal você adicionar algumas dicas técnicas mais focadas para o problema dele, por exemplo, como criar estruturas no HTML para estilos diferentes e organização do código, etc, ficaria com a reposta mais completa e agregaria um valor maior à comunidade.

Comment: +1. dentro do que a pergunta diz, não conseguiria imaginar muito mais o que dizer. Entendo a pergunta como ampla demais para ser respondida em uma postagem apenas. Seria legal se o autor da pergunta resolvesse um problema por vez, em perguntas separadas, e fosse fazendo o site passo a passo, conforme o conhecimento permite.

Comment: Ainda sou novo em desenvolvimento de sites, ainda estou estudando css e html, obrigado pelo concelho